# Get comments that contain specific words Gerrit

Tags: comments, gerrit, review

I want to ask about Gerrit, I'm looking into the review comments on the Nova project, I want to know if I can get all the comments that contain specific words, like 'TEXT'.
I tried comments:'TEXT' but it doesn't work, it even gets a code change that contains no comments at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using single or double quotation marks? It worked pretty well for me in Gerrit 3.4.1, using double quotation marks, as the following example:

```
comment:"shame on me"
```